# Gulp failing default task due to jQuery error for generator-ko

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, gulp, yeoman

So I'm trying to run gulp on my Knockout app which was generated by Yeoman `generator-ko`.

I've cloned my repo (which builds fine on my Macbook) to my Windows 10 box. If I run gulp default I get the following error (full output):

```
[14:33:41] Using gulpfile ~\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\Gulpfile.js
[14:33:41] Starting 'html'...
[14:33:41] Starting 'js:babel'...
[14:33:41] Starting 'css'...
[14:33:41] Finished 'html' after 46 ms
[14:33:41] Finished 'css' after 198 ms
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "src/bower_modules/knockout/dist/knockout.debug.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
[BABEL] Note: The code generator has deoptimised the styling of "src/bower_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".
stream.js:94
      throw er; // Unhandled stream error in pipe.
            ^
SyntaxError: src/bower_modules/jquery/src/intro.js: Unexpected token (45:0)
  43 | // you try to trace through "use strict" call chains. (#13335)
  44 | //"use strict";
> 45 | 
     | ^
    at Parser.pp.raise (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\location.js:24:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\util.js:82:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:425:12)
    at Parser.parseExprAtom (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\plugins\jsx\index.js:412:22)
Process terminated with code 8.
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:236:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:217:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:163:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:145:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:112:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExpression (C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\GitHub\TMPrototype\node_modules\babel-core\node_modules\babylon\lib\parser\expression.js:79:19)
```

When I navigate to `bower_modules/jquery/src/intro.js` the parameter function isn't closed. At first I thought this was just the way it will compile by passing the rest of the code in afterwards.

**jQuery/src/intro.js (notice how it isn't closed)**

```
(function( global, factory ) {

    if ( typeof module === "object" && typeof module.exports === "object" ) {
        // For CommonJS and CommonJS-like environments where a proper `window`
        // is present, execute the factory and get jQuery.
        // For environments that do not have a `window` with a `document`
        // (such as Node.js), expose a factory as module.exports.
        // This accentuates the need for the creation of a real `window`.
        // e.g. var jQuery = require("jquery")(window);
        // See ticket #14549 for more info.
        module.exports = global.document ?
            factory( global, true ) :
            function( w ) {
                if ( !w.document ) {
                    throw new Error( "jQuery requires a window with a document" );
                }
                return factory( w );
            };
    } else {
        factory( global );
    }

// Pass this if window is not defined yet
}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function( window, noGlobal ) {

// Support: Firefox 18+
// Can't be in strict mode, several libs including ASP.NET trace
// the stack via arguments.caller.callee and Firefox dies if
// you try to trace through "use strict" call chains. (#13335)
//"use strict";
```

If I resolve that by closing it, `outro.js` has a similar issue the file just contains:

```
}));
```

Which would almost confirm my thoughts on how it's built.

Any ideas?

Comment: Got the same issue today. Have you had any luck?

Comment: @AndreGallo nope sorry, incredibly frustrating though. I'm thinking about putting a bounty on this.

Comment: @Jezzabeans it seems to be an environmental issue. The generator runs fine on my Macbook Pro (OSX El capitan) but fails on my Windows 10 VM. Will post an answer if I find what the underlying issue is ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After a lot of digging around on this, found the answer in a [PR submitted](https://github.com/SteveSanderson/generator-ko/issues/17) by *nenitiko*.

It's to do with the differences on forward/backward-slash directory separators in OSX/Win environments.

So to fix it, add a reference to `slash = require('slash');` in your gulp file. And then `pathname = slash(pathname);` to the `babelTranspile` function.

Comment: Thanks Andre, I'll test this once I get home.

Comment: Tested and it worked beautifully, thanks for finding this Andre. Enjoy the bounty. Edit: can only award it in 10 hours.

Comment: You are literally a god among men haha! Thanks so much for debugging this.